# Noe4j: How do you handle first seen and last seen properties on import when not in first import statement?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

So I am working with email data.  I was requested to add a count property of times seen for relationships between nodes, and a second requirement to add a first seen and last seen to each relationship and every node but the recipient(the data is external to internal so the recipient does not require the first or last seen).

So I started working with the following imports.  This seems to work fine for the `NO ATTACHMENT OR LINK` if the sender is in the first import, but if the sender is not in the first import the `first and last seen` portion is messed up because the initial set is in the first import.

```
// NO ATTACHMENT OR LINK - FIRST IMPORT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/new_neo_test_1.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld, last_seen: datetime(row.DateTime) })
SET a.first_seen = coalesce(a.last_seen)
MERGE (b:Recipient { name: row.To, last_seen: datetime(row.DateTime) })
SET b.first_seen = coalesce(a.last_seen)
WITH a,b,row
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false"
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {last_seen: datetime(row.DateTime)}, b, {}) YIELD rel as rel1
SET rel1.first_seen = coalesce(rel1.last_seen)
SET rel1.times_seen = coalesce(rel1.times_seen, 0) + 1
RETURN a,b

// NO ATTACHMENT OR LINK - REST OF IMPORTS
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/new_neo_test_2.csv") AS row
WITH row, datetime(row.DateTime) AS dt
MERGE (a:Sender {name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
SET a.last_seen = dt
MERGE (b:Recipient {name: row.To})
SET b.last_seen = dt
WITH a, b, row, dt
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false" 
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel
SET rel.last_seen = dt
SET rel.times_seen = coalesce(rel.times_seen, 0) + 1
RETURN a, b
```

Anyways for the way I am importing this data, is there a better way to do this, so that I dont have to break up the data into an initial import and following imports with a different import statement.  And how should I handle the `first seen` and `last seen` properties if I go about it this way.

Comment: When using the merge statement you can use on crate set and on match set, this should help yoi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic should work for both first and non-first passes:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///sessions/new_neo_test_1.csv" AS row
WITH row, datetime(row.DateTime) AS dt
MERGE (a:Sender {name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
ON CREATE SET a.first_seen = dt
SET a.last_seen = dt
MERGE (b:Recipient {name: row.To})
ON CREATE SET b.first_seen = dt
SET b.last_seen = dt
WITH a, b, row, dt 
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false"
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, b, {}) YIELD rel
SET rel.first_seen = COALESCE(rel.first_seen, dt)
SET rel.last_seen = dt
SET rel.times_seen = COALESCE(rel.times_seen, 0) + 1
RETURN a, b
```

You just need to use the appropriate file path, which should probably be passed as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) instead of being hardcoded, as shown here.

After a [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clause, the optional [ON CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-create) clause is only executed if the `MERGE` created something.

Also, you should never specify mutable properties (like `last_seen`) in a  `MERGE` pattern, as that would just cause the creation of a new node if the mutable property has a new value.

Comment: Thanks again @cybersam and thank you for explaining the mutable properties in a merge pattern portion.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, it would probably make good sense to split out your data load, and separate out the phases of creating the nodes, and then joining them up, i.e.:

- First pass - MERGE the Senders and Receivers from all your CSVs
- Second pass - MATCH the Senders and Receivers, and then join the relationships based on desired logic

Like this you know that the Senders and Receivers are already there when you're adding relationships after